# Can a Battlemaster fighter get a bonus action on a crit when using riposte as his reaction

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, fighter, combat-maneuver

So last night our Great Weapon Master fighter using  his riposte as his reaction, crit with his hit. Was he then able to get another bonus action from Great Weapon Master?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Only if the attack that triggered Riposte is on your turn

Riposte says:

> **When a creature misses you with a melee attack**, you can use your reaction and expend one superiority die to make a melee weapon attack against the creature. If you hit, you add the superiority die to the attack’s damage roll.

If creature misses you with an attack *on your turn* (for example if you triggered an attack of opportunity from them by using your move) and you roll a critical hit then that does indeed trigger Great Weapon Master's first condition:

> **On your turn**, when you score a critical hit with a melee weapon or
> reduce a creature to 0 hit points with one, **you can make one melee
> weapon attack as a bonus action**.

And thus, you can of course make a bonus action melee attack as a result (assuming you haven't already used your bonus action for your turn).

So, the character has now used:

1. 1 reaction to riposte
2. 1 bonus action to make GWM attack

As long as the character had those actions available (ie he did not take a reaction or bonus action earlier in the turn) then this is definitely allowed.

Note: In the body of your question you said

> Was he then able to get **another** bonus action from GWM?

I just wanted to be very clear here that, by doing what they did, **they are not getting or using an additional bonus action**. You may get and use only one bonus action per turn so this would not be possible. However, this is not an issue for the fighter in the example since he is using a reaction and a bonus action (not two bonus actions).